# Error: error:060800C8:digital envelope routines:EVP_DigestInit_ex:disabled for FIPS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, openshift, redhat, cryptojs

Facing this error while deploying a react app on openshift using Redhat ubi8-minimal base image.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by adding the following lines to the beginning of `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash;
crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == "md5" ? "sha256" : algorithm);
```

From a Dockerfile, this can be done with a sed command:

```
RUN sed -i "s|const path = require('path');|const path = require('path');const crypto = require('crypto'); const crypto_orig_createHash = crypto.createHash; crypto.createHash = algorithm => crypto_orig_createHash(algorithm == 'md5' ? 'sha256' : algorithm);|g" /app/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
```

This solution originated in a discussion on the [webpack GitHub forum](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/13572#issuecomment-923736472).